Consulta PHP MYSQL exceptuando el lugar de un cargo
Hola a todos tengo un problema hago una consulta a una base de datos y limito la búsqueda tanto el mismo lugar (municipio) que sea el mismo lugar almacenado en la variable de session $municipioe del que inicia sesión. para que solo encuentre las personas de su mismo municipio. También limito la consulta a solo los cargos dentro del IN cargos (solo aparecerán esas personas con esos cargos)
SELECT id, nombre, identificacion, municipio, cargo, estadotrabajador 
FROM tabla 
WHERE municipio IN ('$municipioe') 
AND cargo IN ('ASESOR', 'AUXILIAR','CONDUCTOR') 
AND estadotrabajador IN ('ACTIVO', 'INACTIVO') 
AND ......

Todo resulta bien, pero hay una excepción el cargo CONDUCTOR es de otro municipio y este no aparece en la búsqueda y debería, como le pongo esa excepción al cargo Conductor para que aparezca aunque este no sea igual al municipio $municipioe.

Si los municipios no tienen el municipio de ese conductor... por que entonces no agregas el municipio a la variable ?

podrias probar con un OR:
AND cargo IN ('ASESOR', 'AUXILIAR')
OR cargo IN ('CONDUCTOR')


Pero en dado caso te recomiendo que uses un join y separes el campo cargo de tu tabla
--Crea primero la tabla cargos

CREATE TABLE Cargos (
    Id INT(50) NOT_NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Cargo VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)


SELECT nombre, identificacion, municipio, cargo, estadotrabajador
FROM tabla INNER JOIN cargos

-- Donde el municipio de la sesion sea igual a los que tienes registrados dentro de tu base de datos
WHERE municipio = municipio 
AND cargo IN ("ASESOR", "AUXILIAR", "CONDUCTOR")
-- Cambia este valor a un valor entero o booleano
AND estadotrabajador = 1

Esto deberia traerte todos los empleados con cargo Conductores sin la necesidad de que este en el mismo municipio

